# Sony Vaio VPCEH26EN Wifi not working after changing OS

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, wifi-driver

I have been using Sony Vaio  [VPCEH26EN](http://www.sony.co.in/support/product/VPCEH26EN) , since two years. Few days back I changed the pre-installed OS Windows 7 Home Basic to Windows 7 Ultimate, both 64 bit. After that wifi on my device is not working, I have also installed all the drivers properly, but still the wifi switch is not working.

I complained Sony Care about the same, but their solutions of re-installing the drivers is not working. I need help to solve this, if anyone have encountered similar problem and have come up with workaround to solve it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Computer--> Click Manage---> Device Manager ---> Find your network controller(yellow question marked)---> Right click to find details---> Copy Hardware id.

Goto devid.info and paste the hardware id you copied earlier. If the drivers are available for your OS then download them.

If not available. Download the drivers with same architecture of your OS. Run them in compatibilty mode for the OS they are made for.

Hope it might solve your problem.

Otherwise you may download DRP(Driver pack Solution) from kickass torrents.